# Getting Syntax Error with MySQL Workbench 6.0 Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am a newbie to mysql, I and I have written a stored procedure in which I am always getting syntax errors , I am using SQL Workbench 6.0, Could some one please help know what am I doing wrong.

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `loginAuthentication`(IN user_name VARCHAR(45),IN pass VARCHAR(45),OUT returnvalue INT)

    BEGIN
           DECLARE no_of_records INT; (Syntax Error on this Line)

           SELECT COUNT(*) INTO no_of_records
           FROM tablename.registration 
           WHERE tablename.registration.user_name=user_name AND tablename.registration.pass=pass; 

           IF no_of_records = 1 THEN (Syntax Error on this Line)
           SET returnvalue = 1;
           END IF; (Syntax Error on this Line)
    END; (Syntax Error on this Line)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the delimiter. Otherwise MySQL thinks that your procedure ends after the very first `;`

Write it like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `loginAuthentication`(IN user_name VARCHAR(45),IN pass VARCHAR(45),OUT returnvalue INT)

BEGIN
       DECLARE no_of_records INT;

       SELECT COUNT(*) INTO no_of_records
       FROM tablename.registration 
       WHERE tablename.registration.user_name=user_name AND tablename.registration.pass=pass; 

       IF no_of_records = 1 THEN 
       SET returnvalue = 1;
       END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And btw, Workbench has nothing to do with it. It's just a client to MySQL.